# In Go language how to take input step by step from file as like freopen in c/c++

Tags: go

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    freopen("in.txt", "r", stdin);

    int n, val, sum=0;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &val);
        sum += val;
    }

    printf("%d\n", sum);  
}
```

Input (**in.txt**):

```
5
1 2 3 4 5
```

Output:

```
15
```

In C language above program will automatically take data from **in.txt** file. I do not need to provide data in console.

Is there any way to do this in **GO** language? So that I do not need to provide huge amount of data manually or add that in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your C program is just scanning the tokens one by one. Of course there are many ways to accomplish this in Go. I'd recommend the `bufio` package but really all you need is a reader and something to convert string to int. Below is an example that is similar to your C program.

```
import "bufio"
import "strconv"

file, err := os.Open("in.txt")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer file.Close()

scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)

base := 0

if scanner.Scan() {
    base += strconv.Atoi(scanner.Text())
}

scanner.Split(bufio.ScanWords)

for scanner.Scan() {
    base += strconv.Atoi(scanner.Text())
}

if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Println(base)
```

Comment: @AerofoilKite it's pseudo code which I haven't tested, I suppose I can modify it for you if you can't make it work...

Comment: It will be helpful for me. I didn't get it yet

Comment: @AerofoilKite alright, here's a working example; https://play.golang.org/p/55V3HK9eSs I left out the first line for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to scan only from stdin, open the file directly.

The `fmt` package has a series of [`fmt.Fscan*`](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Fscanf) functions for this.